# Emojis from MySQL database showing up as '?'

Tags: php, mysql

In my Phorum database I have changed the collation to utf8mb4_general_ci and successfully got emojis stored in the message body, however when you try to load the message it just displays a single '?'

Could this be an issue with the character set in use? I've found this:

```
// The charset to use for displaying special characters.
$PHORUM["DATA"]['CHARSET']="UTF-8";
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this page:[mathiasbynens.be](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4), "MySQL’s utf8 charset only partially implements proper UTF-8 encoding. It can only store UTF-8-encoded symbols that consist of one to three bytes; encoded symbols that take up four bytes aren’t supported."

To execute this sql in mysql:
ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

Comment: Have now changed to utf8mb4_unicode_ci but still the same.

Comment: you inserted your database name where it says 'database_name', right?

Comment: According the article I originally cited, mySQL must be at least version 5.5.3

Comment: Surely it wouldn't let me store the emoji if there was an issue?